# Surefire not running all tests

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to use a combination of Surefire (or even Failsafe if I can configure it to work properly), to run my integration tests for a personal project. At present it will run 2/3 of my integration tests. The 3 classes are `GameDbApplicationTests`, `UserDAOImplTest`, & `GameDAOImplTest`. The first two will run, while the last one will not.

Logically it *should* be running all of the classes titled `*Test`, so I'm not sure what is going on here. I am capable of running each test class *manually* using IntelliJ, but the Maven test goal will not execute all of the test classes.

#### `.\mvnw test` output is included [here](https://logpaste.com/WaxrC4qM)

Note that the test lists `GameDbApplicationTests` & `UserDAOImplTest`, but not `GameDAOImplTest` for whatever reason.

### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.StruckCroissant</groupId>
    <artifactId>Game-DB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Game-DB</name>
    <description>Game Database Search Engine</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.vorburger.mariaDB4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariaDB4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### GameDAOImplTest

```
package com.StruckCroissant.GameDB.core.game;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

import com.StruckCroissant.GameDB.TestDbConfig;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDbConfig.class, GameDAOImpl.class})
class GameDAOImplTest {

  @Qualifier("db-game")
  @Autowired
  private GameDAOImpl underTest;

  @Qualifier("testTemplate")
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Test
  public void shouldGetAllGames() {
    // given
    // nothing
    // when
    List<Game> allGames = underTest.selectAllGames();

    // then
    allGames.forEach((game) -> assertThat(game).isInstanceOf(Game.class));
    assertThat(allGames.size()).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(30250);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldGetGameById() {
    // given
    int[] validGames = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] invalidGames = {-4, -56, -3, 879627};
    List<Optional<Game>> validResult = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Optional<Game>> invalidResult = new ArrayList<>();

    // when
    for (int gameInt : validGames) {
      Optional<Game> currentGameOpt = underTest.selectGameById(gameInt);
      validResult.add(currentGameOpt);
    }
    for (int gameInt : invalidGames) {
      Optional<Game> currentGameOpt = underTest.selectGameById(gameInt);
      invalidResult.add(currentGameOpt);
    }

    // then
    validResult.forEach((gameOpt) -> assertThat(gameOpt).get().isInstanceOf(Game.class));
    invalidResult.forEach((gameOpt) -> assertThat(gameOpt).isEmpty());
  }
}
```

### UserDAOImplTest

```
package com.StruckCroissant.GameDB.core.user;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.catchThrowable;

import com.StruckCroissant.GameDB.TestDbConfig;
import com.StruckCroissant.GameDB.core.game.Game;
import java.util.List;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDbConfig.class, UserDAOImpl.class})
class UserDAOImplTest {

  @Qualifier("db-user")
  @Autowired
  private UserDAOImpl underTest;

  @Qualifier("testTemplate")
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
    JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "user");
  }

  @NotNull
  private String insertDefaultUserDb() {
    User user = new User("test_username", "test_password", UserRoleEnum.USER, false, true);
    underTest.insertUser(user);
    return "test_username";
  }

  @NotNull
  private String insertUserDb(String username) {
    User user = new User(username, "test_password", UserRoleEnum.USER, false, true);
    underTest.insertUser(user);
    return username;
  }

  @NotNull
  private Integer getUidFromUserObj(User userFromDb) {
    return userFromDb.getId().orElseThrow();
  }

  @NotNull
  private Integer getTestUidFromUsernameDb(String test_username) {
    return underTest
        .selectUserByUsername(test_username)
        .flatMap(User::getId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("User not found in DB"));
  }

  @Test
  @Order(1)
  void shouldInsertAndSelectNewUser() {
    // given
    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();

    // when
    boolean userExists = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).isPresent();

    // then
    assertThat(userExists).isTrue();
  }

  @Test
  void shouldGetUidFromuser() {
    // given
    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();

    // when
    int uid = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).flatMap(User::getId).orElse(0);

    // then
    assertThat(uid).isNotEqualTo(0);
  }

  @Test
  void shouldUpdateUser() {
    // given
    // Init user
    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();
    int initUidDb = getTestUidFromUsernameDb(test_username);

    // Updated user
    String new_username = "new_account_420_updated";
    String new_password = "password_updated";
    User updatedUser = new User(new_username, new_password, UserRoleEnum.USER, false, true);

    // Updated user
    underTest.updateUserById(initUidDb, updatedUser);
    User updatedUserDb = getTestUserFromUidDb(initUidDb);
    int updatedUidDb = getUidFromUserObj(updatedUserDb);

    // then
    assertThat(updatedUidDb).isEqualTo(initUidDb);
    assertThat(updatedUserDb.getUsername()).isEqualTo(new_username);
    assertThat(updatedUserDb.getPassword()).isEqualTo(new_password);
  }

  private User getTestUserFromUidDb(int initUidDb) {
    return underTest
        .selectUserById(initUidDb)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found in database"));
  }

  @Test
  void shouldDeleteUser() {
    // given
    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();
    User userFromDb = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).get();
    int uidFromDb = getUidFromUserObj(userFromDb);

    // when
    underTest.deleteUserById(uidFromDb);
    boolean userExists = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).isPresent();

    // then
    assertThat(userExists).isFalse();
  }

  @Test
  void shouldGetSavedGames() {
    // given
    int[] games = {1, 2, 3}; // Test games

    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();
    User userFromDb = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).orElseThrow();
    int uid = getUidFromUserObj(userFromDb);

    // when
    for (int gid : games) {
      underTest.insertSavedGame(uid, gid);
    }

    // then
    assertThat(underTest.selectSavedGames(uid).size()).isNotEqualTo(0);
    underTest.selectSavedGames(uid).forEach(g -> assertThat(g).isExactlyInstanceOf(Game.class));
  }

  @Test
  void shouldDeleteSavedGame() {
    // given
    int[] games = {1, 2, 3}; // Test games

    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();
    User userFromDb = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).orElseThrow();
    int uid = getUidFromUserObj(userFromDb);

    // when
    for (int gid : games) {
      underTest.insertSavedGame(uid, gid);
    }
    underTest.deleteSavedGame(uid, games[0]);
    underTest.deleteSavedGame(uid, games[1]);
    underTest.deleteSavedGame(uid, games[2]);

    // then
    assertThat(underTest.selectSavedGames(uid).size()).isEqualTo(0);
  }

  @Test
  void shouldDetectNonUniqueUser() {
    // given
    String test_username = insertDefaultUserDb();
    User userFromDb = underTest.selectUserByUsername(test_username).orElseThrow();

    // when
    boolean userIsUnique = underTest.userIsUnique(userFromDb);

    // then
    assertThat(userIsUnique).isFalse();
  }

  @Test
  void shouldSelectAllUsers() {
    // given
    String test_username = insertUserDb("test_username1");
    String test_username2 = insertUserDb("test_username2");
    String test_username3 = insertUserDb("test_username3");

    // when
    List<User> users = underTest.selectAllUsers();

    // then
    assertThat(users.size()).isEqualTo(3);
    users.forEach(
        (User u) -> {
          assertThat(u).isExactlyInstanceOf(User.class);
          assertThat(u.getUsername()).isIn(test_username, test_username2, test_username3);
        });
  }

  @Test
  void shouldThrowOnNullId() {
    // given
    User user = new User("test_username", "test_password", UserRoleEnum.USER, false, true);

    // when
    Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> underTest.userIsUnique(user));

    // then
    assertThat(thrown).isExactlyInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class);
  }
}
```

### GameDbApplicationTests

```
package com.StruckCroissant.GameDB;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class GameDbApplicationTests {

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {}
}
```

### TestDbConfig

```
package com.StruckCroissant.GameDB;

import ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcessException;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DBConfiguration;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DBConfigurationBuilder;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class TestDbConfig {

  @Bean
  public DBConfiguration dbConfig() {
    DBConfigurationBuilder config = DBConfigurationBuilder.newBuilder();
    //Port not set to allow new instances to be generated for batch of tests
    config.setSecurityDisabled(true);
    return config.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource(
      @Autowired DBConfiguration dbConfig,
      @Value("${test.datasource.name}") String databaseName,
      @Value("${test.datasource.username}") String datasourceUsername,
      @Value("${test.datasource.username}") String datasourcePassword,
      @Value("${test.datasource.driver-class-name}") String datasourceDriver)
      throws ManagedProcessException {
    DB db = DB.newEmbeddedDB(dbConfig);
    db.start();
    db.createDB(databaseName, "root", "");
    db.source("db/init/schema.sql", databaseName);

    DBConfiguration dbConfiguration = db.getConfiguration();

    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName(datasourceDriver)
        .url(dbConfiguration.getURL(databaseName))
        .username(datasourceUsername)
        .password(datasourcePassword)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean("testTemplate")
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which unit testing framework do you use? JUnit 4 or JUnit Jupiter (aka. JUnit 5?) Also a log output of your run would be helpful.. ?

Comment: Also, it would help if you posted the relevant tests, as well as the output of `mvn test`. If you mean you can't see the results in your IDE then that's likely because some precondition for the third test fails

Comment: What I see in your setup is also you are defining versions of hibernate-core, spring-data-rest-webmvc which is a bad idea.. Keep there versions defined by the parent... I doubt that is a good idea..Why do you define a dependency to org.jetbrains:annotations with a version `RELEASE` which is simply wrong... and should already produce a WARNING during your build...

Comment: I fixed the dependency issues you mentioned and edited my question to have some more details. I am currently using JUnit 4 to run the tests & specifying `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` in each test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by myself. The problem was due to inadvertent usage of both JUnit4 and Junit5.

I was using the `@AfterEach` annotation in my test classes, which is defined by Junit5 and therefore imported into the test classes. I was also adding JUnit5 via the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency. After removing all refrences to JUnit5 the issue is resolved.